# How to get newly created _id from Meteor.loginWithFacebook() method?

Tags: facebook, meteor

```
    Trying to integrate social media login for my system. 
    For that I have used following method
       Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err,res){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
            }else{
                if(res){
                    console.log("result : " + res);
                }

                FlowRouter.go('/');
            }
        });
Above method successfully creating user and there is a successful
entry in users collection too. I want to access that newly created _id.
Is there any callback available . Thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a user has logged in (regardless of the login method), you can use [`Meteor.userId()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-userId) to get the id.

So in your case, as soon as the login with facebook is successful, `Meteor.userId()` will return that new user `_id`.

In case you want to full user document, you can use [`Meteor.user()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-user) instead.